# How can I tell if a push notification was successfully delivered in Azure NotificationHubs?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I have an app with a simple messenger component to it. When user1 sends a message to user2 I am using Azure Notification Hubs to send a push notification to user2. Since I am using Notification Hubs to register the user's devices for push notifications, I don't know which phone OS's they have registered with, so just queue a notification for each type I support:

```
NotificationOutcome outcome1 = await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(jsoniOSPayload, tags);
NotificationOutcome outcome2 = await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(jsonAndroidPayload, tags);
...(etc.)
```

However, we need to handle the case where an app has been deleted. When this happens, we need to send the user an email if a push notification could not be sent to any of their devices.

My question is: how can I tell if at least one notification was successfully delivered to a users device? I know about the NotificationHubClient.EnableTestSend property, which does cause the NotificationOutcome object to have a success count. This would work perfectly, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.enabletestsend?view=azurenotificationhubs-1.0.7#Microsoft_Azure_NotificationHubs_NotificationHubClient_EnableTestSend) indicates this would not be optimal in production:

> "When test send is enabled, the following occurs: All notifications
>   only reach up to 10 devices for each send call.The Send* methods
>   return a list of the outcomes for all those notification deliveries.
>   The possible outcomes are the same as displayed in telemetry. Outcomes
>   includes things like authentication errors, throttling errors,
>   successful deliveries, and so on.This mode is for test purposes only,
>   not for production, and is throttled."

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I tell if at least one notification was successfully delivered to a users device?

As you mentioned that `NotificationHubClient.EnableTestSend` is used for debugging and limited to 10 devices.
If we want to get the count of successfully delivered, we can use function `NotificationHubClient.GetNotificationOutcomeDetailsAsync(string notificationId)`, more details please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.getnotificationoutcomedetailsasync?view=azurenotificationhubs-1.0.7).

Demo code:

```
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://notificationnamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxx", "NotificationHub Name");
string message = "{\"title\":\"((Notification title))\",\"description\":\"Hello from Azure\"}";
           var result = await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(message); //GCM for example.
           var notificationDetails = await hub.GetNotificationOutcomeDetailsAsync(result.NotificationId);
           return notificationDetails;
```

[image]

**Note**: It is just for standard pricing tier.

Comment: I think not using the standard pricing tear was my problem. I was trying to find a notification ID somewhere, but with the lower tiers it seems that the value is just not in the response. Thanks for your reply!